# IntelliJ keeps warning for import prop-types with ReactJS and Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, intellij-idea, types, warnings

My IntelliJ keeps warning me when I try to use an object as a type. It will highlight the area, and also screw up formatting when I try to write my code.

**I am working with ReactJS and Typescript**. It compiles perfectly fine, yet IntelliJ insists on making it a problem.

[Warning that shows up.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7JNp.png)

[Code without blue text bubble covering it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9PLkc.png)

The syntax should be fine. I don't know how to stop IntelliJ from doing this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try defining `interface` above class and use it in `Component<interface>`.

Comment: So there's no way to stop IntelliJ from doing this, instead of a workaround? I can also temporarily satisfy IntelliJ by importing 'prop-types' from React, and then removing it.

Comment: from the screenshot I can see that syntax errors are reported, code can't be parsed. But similar code is correctly highlighted for me, no errors/warnings are there. What errors can you see? Please hover over the red highlighted statements and provide a screenshot of error tooltip. Also, please make sure that the file extension and icon are shown on screenshot

Comment: Modified the second screenshot so the file extension is visible with the error message. It compiles fine.